# If a class might be inherited, should every function be virtual?

Tags: c++, oop

In C++, a coder doesn't know whether other coders will inherit his class. Should he make every function in that class virtual? Are there any drawbacks? Or is it just not acceptable at all?

Comment: Part of C++'s inherent design philosophy is that the base class knows all the classes that derive from it.

Comment: @Alexander, where did you read that?

Comment: @Alexander Rafferty: Where in the world did you get that idea? In any case, it's entirely wrong.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov, @Jerry Coffin- I don't think that statement is that off the mark.  True, you don't need to know every class that derives from the base class, but you should know if *some* class is going to derive off the class, since you'll have taken appropriate precautions to ensure it works correctly, such as adding a virtual destructor.

Comment: @emplatetypedef: It's completely off the mark. Yes, if you want something to be a base class, you design it to be a base class (which usually, but certainly not always includes a virtual dtor). That implies *nothing* about know "all the classes that derived from it." or anything similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++, you should only make a class inheritable from if you intend for it to be used polymorphically.  The way that you treat polymorphic objects in C++ is very different from how you treat other objects.  You don't tend to put polymorphic classes on the stack, or pass them by or return them from functions by value, since this can lead to **slicing**.  Polymorphic objects tend to be heap-allocated, be passed around and returns by pointer or by reference, etc.

If you design a class to not be inherited from and then inherit from it, you cause all sorts of problems.  If the destructor isn't marked virtual, you can't delete the object through a base class pointer without causing undefined behavior.  Without the member functions marked `virtual`, they can't be overridden in a derived class.

As a general rule in C++, when you design the class, determine whether you want it be inherited from.  If you do, mark the appropriate functions `virtual` and give it a `virtual` destructor.  You might also disable the copy assignment operator to avoid slicing.  Similarly, if you want the class not to be inheritable, don't give it any of these functions.  In most cases it's a logic error to inherit from a class that wasn't designed to be inherited from, and most of the times you'd want to do this you can often use *composition* instead of inheritance to achieve this effect.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin- Yes, that's absolutely true.  I'll go clarify that.

Comment: Can you define slicing or provide a link?

Comment: @WW, @Andy Leman - here's a pretty good link: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~hoover/Courses/201/201-New-Notes/lectures/section/slice.htm

Comment: Can you define composition or provide a link?

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you *design* your class to be used either as a *value type* or a *polymorphic type*. See, for example, [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/value-vs-ref-semantics.html).

Answer (score 4):

No, not usually.

A non-virtual function enforces class-invariant behavior. A virtual function doesn't. As such, the person writing the base class should think about whether the behavior of a particular function is/should be class invariant or not.

While it's *possible* for a design to allow all behaviors to vary in derived classes, it's fairly unusual. It's usually a pretty good clue that the person who wrote the class either didn't think much about its design, lacked the resolve to make a decision.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a class to be used by other people, you should put a lot of thought into your interface and try to work out how your class will be used. Then make the decisions like which functions should be virtual.

Or better yet write a test case for your class, using it how you expect it to be used, and then make the interface work for that. You might be surprised what you find out doing it. Things you thought were absolutely necessary might turn out to be rarely needed and things that you thought were not going to be used might turn out to be the most useful methods. Doing it this way around will save you time not doing unnecessary work in the long run and end up with solid designs.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Adding a virtual function doesn't make the *object* bigger (in most implementations), but only increases the size of the vtable itself (which there is only one instance of).

Comment: -1: Virtual tables are not part of C++. But the implementation of virtual tables means that one or a thousand only adds one pointer to the object. So the size of the object is not affected by the number of virtual functions.

Comment: @greg, Obviously my understanding of how c++ works is flawed. Thanks I'll remove that.

Answer (score 2):

[Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999603/in-c-one-coder-dont-know-what-other-coders-will-inherit-his-class-should-h/4999651#4999651) and [Dominic McDonnell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999603/in-c-one-coder-dont-know-what-other-coders-will-inherit-his-class-should-h/4999637#4999637) have already covered the most important points.

I'll just add an observation, that in the time of MFC (middle 1990s) I was *very* annoyed with the lack of ways hook into things. For example, the documentation suggested copying MFC's source code for printing and modifying, instead of overriding behavior. Because nothing was virtual there.

There are of course a zillion+1 ways to provide "hooks", but virtual methods are one easy way. They're needed in badly designed classes, so that the client code can fix things, but in those badly designed classes the methods are not virtual. For classes with better design there is not so much need to override behavior, and so for those classes making methods virtual by default (and non-virtual only as active choice) can be counter-productive; as Jerry remarked, virtuals provide opportunites for derived classes to screw up.

There are design patterns that can be employed to minimize the possibilities of screw-ups.

For example, wrapping internal virtuals in exposed non-virtual methods with sanity checks, and, for example, using decoupled event handling (where appropriate) instead of virtuals.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

When you create a class, and you want that class to be used polymorphically you have to consider that the class has two different interfaces. The user interface is defined by the set of public functions that are available in your base class, and that should pretty much cover all operations that users want to perform on objects of your class. This interface is defined by the access qualifiers, and in particular the `public` qualifier.

There is a second interface, that defines how your class is to be extended. At that level you have to think on what behavior you want to be overridden by extending classes, and what elements of your object you want to provide to extending classes. You offer access to derived classes by means of the `protected` qualifier, and you offer extension points by means of virtual functions.

You should try to follow the Non-Virtual Interface idiom whenever possible. That idiom (google for it) basically tries to fully separate the two interfaces by not having public virtual functions. Users call non-virtual functions, and those in turn call on configurable functionalities by means of protected/private virtual functions. This clearly separates extension points from the class interface.

There is a single case, where `virtual` has to be part of the user interface: the destructor. If you want to offer your users the ability to destroy derived objects through pointers to the base, then you have to provide a virtual destructor. Else you just provide a protected non-virtual one.

Answer (score 0):

He should code the functions as it is, he shouldn't make them virtual at all, as in the circumstances specified by you.

The reasons being 
    1> The CLASS CODER would obviously have certain use of functions he is using.
    2> The inherited class may or may not make use of these functions as per requirement.
    3> Any function may be overwritten in derived class without any errors.